# How to Define Object type that contains properties as number in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Hi i'm struggling to create a type for networkConfig, i tried the following one but it's not working properly, notice that property is an Integer!!

```js
type networkConfigType = {
  number: {
    name: string;
    ethUsdPriceFeed: string;
  };
};
```

```js
const networkConfig  = {
  4: {
    name  : "rinkeby",
    ethUsdPriceFeed: "0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e",
  },
137: {
      name: "polygon",
      ethUsdPriceFeed: "0xF9680D99D6C9589e2a93a78A04A279e509205945",
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type networkConfigType = Record<number, {
    name: string;
    ethUsdPriceFeed: string;
}>;
```

Comment: Thank you so much broo!!!, big cheeeeer to youuuu

Comment: @LajosArpad i already accepted it

Comment: @ABDELLATIFANAFLOUS if you accept an answer, then a green check mark appears below the vote counter.